# What's the difference between sentence with "though" and without?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation

For example:

> It would be nice though.

vs.

> It would be nice.

In a real conversation scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It would be nice" is a neutral or positive statement, saying that if some thing were to happen, that would be good.

"It would be nice *though*" adds an element of wistfulness or regret.
It is an acknowledgement that the good thing **will not happen**.

Off the top of my head I can't think of a conversation where I would say "It would be nice" on its own. Instead I would say "**That** would be nice" like so:

> **A:** Would you like a massage?
> **B:** That would be nice.

In that context "That would be nice" means "Yes, please."

> **A:** Would you like a massage?
> **B:** I don't have time. It would be nice though.

In that context "It would be nice though" is a polite way of saying "No."
**If** it were to happen, it would be nice, but it will not happen.